# Linking from child, maintaining parent reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, parent

I have an issue with a relationship between links followed from a child element, whereas they lose the ability to update from the parent frame.  I am utilizing this code to call the reference document;

```
function Open_Ref() {
X = (screen.width - 900) / 2;
Y = (screen.height - 700) / 2;
settings = 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=700,width=900,top=' + Y + ',left=' + X;
theURL = '../dir/foo.htm#' + parent.MAIN.frame_id;
Ref_Window = window.open(theURL, 'Ref', settings);
Ref_Window.focus();
Ref_Window.moveTo(X, Y);
}

function Refresh_Ref() {
theURL = '../dir/foo.htm#' + parent.MAIN.frame_id;
if (Ref_Window != null) {
Ref_Window.updateRef(parent.MAIN.frame_id);
}
```

This opens the reference window and within that reference, it contains code in order to update a frame reference from the parent frame;

```
function updateRef(frame){
        window.location.hash=frame;
}
```

The main frame calls contains a setTimeout function that calls the update;

```
setTimeout("Refresh_Ref()",1000);
```

This all works correct, and as the frame of the parent.MAIN is navigated, the child updates to the appropriate frame.  My issue is that I have multiple "personalized" references, linked from the reference window (basically duplicates of the original reference child), let's call them, foo1.htm, foo2.htm, etc, when these are accessed, they lose the ability to update to the frame of the parent, even when you navigate back to the foo.htm file.

I realize that the original Open_Ref() function only calls out this one file, however, I have attempted to add multiple functions in and it does not seem to work.

Any ideas, possibly utilize a Boolean statement to check to see which foo.htm file is open before running the function?

Comment: I am sorry, I've read it three times and I have a hard time figuring what you need... What I do not understand is that you use parent data which means you are in a child window, to open a new window. That would mean you have about at least 3 windows right? Now, how do they interact between each other exactly? And what are those references you are talking about? Pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion.  So with the help from another local scripter, we were able to figure this issue out yesterday.  To answer your question, there are only two windows open at this time, one parent (a lesson guide) and a child window (reference guide), as you navigate the parent lesson frame, the child needs to refresh to update the frame to the top of the page.  Now the issue was arising when we selected a separate (personalized) reference window that would update in the current frame (window.replace).

The issue we had was that there was an onunload method in the body tag that was cancelling the focus on the child when you navigate away from the child.  Once we removed that onunload tag, it maintained focus from the parent so it was able to continue to run the Refresh_Ref() function.  It did throw an error because that function was also looking for a null window, so when you closed the reference window the script would error.  To mitigate this, we created a catch to catch the error and null the window.

No worries!  Thanks for your assistance!!